# the negation of $A \veebar B \veebar C $??

Tags: propositional-calculus

I need to know the negation of $A \veebar B \veebar C $, with [$\veebar$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)

thanks in advance!!

Comment: It is $\neg (A \veebar B \veebar C )$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The truth table for $A\veebar B \veebar C$ [is](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth+table+for+%28A+xor+B+xor+C%29)

[image: Truth table for $A\veebar B \veebar C$].

Therefore the truth table for its negation [is](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth+table+for+~%28A+xor+B+xor+C%29)

[image: Truth table for the negation of $A\veebar B \veebar C$].

Now you can construct the formula that yields the truth table above by inspecting it:

$$\underbrace{(A\land B\land \neg C)}_{\large \text{1st true line}} \lor \underbrace{(A\land \neg B\land C)}_{\large \text{2nd true line}}\lor \ldots$$

It's not pretty, but it works.

Comment: What have you used to create those tables?

Comment: @dtldarek Check the links in the answer to be surprised at how easy it is. (Thank you, amWhy).

Comment: Why that doesn't surprise me... Thanks ;-)

Comment: From terms page: "It is permitted to use and post individual, incidental results or small groups of results from Wolfram|Alpha on non-commercial websites and blogs, provided those results are properly credited to Wolfram|Alpha". I try to do something like [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A26306+wolfram+alpha), and I think it is a good practice to attribute the source. Anyway, good job.

Comment: @dtldarek I sually try to mention it in my answer in a natural way whenever I use WA. I couldn't find one this time and since the links are there anyway, I kept it as it is.

Answer (score 3):

It means either none of them are true or exactly two of them are.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $\veebar$ means $\mathtt{xor}$, formula 
$$a_1 \veebar a_2 \veebar \ldots \veebar a_n$$

means that *odd* number of elements $a_i$-s is true. Interpreting truth as $1$ and falsehood as $0$ we arrive at

$$a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_n \equiv 1 \pmod{2}.$$

Naturally, its negation is that *even* number of elements is true,

$$a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_n \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$$

which can be transformed to

$$a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_n + 1 \equiv 1 \pmod{2},$$

that is

$$a_1 \veebar a_2 \veebar \ldots \veebar a_n \veebar \mathtt{true}.$$

In your case this is equivalent to $A \veebar B \veebar C \veebar \mathtt{true}$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$